# REST service not called from iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm trying to hit a rest service from ios app. The service is called except in one scenario. The same service is called when I run the app in simulator or in iPhone connected to Xcode in all the possible scenarios. Once again, after downloading the ipa, I tried the same scenario and the service is not called.

Comment: can you provide more information and also a bit of code? are you sure that the service _is not called_? then you'll have a local issue in your code that causes your program's execution path not to get to the point where the service should be called. or is it possible that the service _is actually called_, but that you are getting an error back or anything else goes wrong with the connection?

Comment: try with easy and simpale comon method
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33767908/volunteermatch-api-objective-c/33886449#33886449