# afnetworking 3.0 Migration: how to POST with headers and HTTP Body

Tags: ios, objective-c, post, afnetworking, afnetworking-3

I am trying to make a POST request which has HTTPHeader Fields and a HTTP body to the youtube API.

Previously in version 2.0 of AFNetworking, I used to do it this way which worked:

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"snippet": @{@"textOriginal":self.commentToPost.text,@"parentId":self.commentReplyingTo.commentId}};

NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/comments?part=snippet&access_token=%@",[[LoginSingleton sharedInstance] getaccesstoken]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters
   options:0
     error:&error];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

// And finally, add it to HTTP body and job done.
[request setHTTPBody:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];



AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer.timeoutInterval=[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"timeoutInterval"] longValue];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [manager HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Reply JSON: %@", responseObject);


    }
} failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@, %@, %@, %@, %@", error, operation.responseObject, operation.responseData, operation.responseString, operation.request);

}];
[operation start];
```

The migration docs for version 3.0 replaces `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` with `AFHTTPSessionManager`
However I can't seem to find a `HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest` method for the `AFHTTPSessionManager`.

I tried using the `constructingBodyWithBlock` but it doesn't work maybe because I am not doing it correctly.

This is what I have so far which doesn't work:

```
NSDictionary *body = @{@"snippet": @{@"topLevelComment":@{@"snippet":@{@"textOriginal":self.commentToPost.text}},@"videoId":self.videoIdPostingOn}};

NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:body
   options:0
     error:&error];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
AFJSONRequestSerializer *serializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
serializer.timeoutInterval= [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"timeoutInterval"] longValue];
[serializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[serializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];


[manager POST:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet&access_token=%@",[[LoginSingleton sharedInstance] getaccesstoken]] parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData>  _Nonnull formData) {

    [formData appendPartWithHeaders:nil body:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

}  progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Reply JSON: %@", responseObject);

} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@, %@, %@, %@, %@", error, operation.responseObject, operation.responseData, operation.responseString, operation.request);

}];
```

Comment: can i know your body message that u want to post and url u r hitting. then sure i can give u sample working code.

Comment: @Imran Thanks for the reply! It's in my post at the top. The "body" dictionary is what I want to post. Previously I would convert it to a JSON String and then the dataUsingEncoding which I would set as the HTTPBody.

Code is included above.

Comment: need one help it would save my time just make sample code of afnetwork with 2.0 and uplaod dropbox or github. if u could do that it would be pretty good. I could see some token based authentication. it would take me undestand your scenario first rather then that u could make one sample working in 2.0. hope u understand

Comment: @Imran do you have a youtube api key? If so, then I can do that

Comment: no i don't have that key you could gives ur alternate working keys. later you can change that

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I was able to figure this out myself.

Here's the solution.

First, you need to create the `NSMutableURLRequest` from `AFJSONRequestSerializer` first where you can set the method type to POST.

On this request, you get to `setHTTPBody` after you have set your `HTTPHeaderFields`. Make sure to set the body after you have set the Header fields for content-type, or else the api will give a 400 error.

Then on the manager create a `dataTaskWithRequest` using the above `NSMutableURLRequest`. Don't forget to `resume` the dataTask at the very end or else nothing will get sent yet. Here's my solution code, hopefully someone gets to use this successfully:

```
NSDictionary *body = @{@"snippet": @{@"topLevelComment":@{@"snippet":@{@"textOriginal":self.commentToPost.text}},@"videoId":self.videoIdPostingOn}};
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:body options:0 error:&error];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet&access_token=%@",[[LoginSingleton sharedInstance] getaccesstoken]] parameters:nil error:nil];

req.timeoutInterval= [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"timeoutInterval"] longValue];
[req setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[req setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[req setHTTPBody:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


[[manager dataTaskWithRequest:req completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    if (!error) {
        NSLog(@"Reply JSON: %@", responseObject);

        if ([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
              //blah blah
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@, %@, %@", error, response, responseObject);
    }
}] resume];
```

Comment: I don't see any difference in your code and mine unless I am missing something?? Mine has worked fine for me in multiple projects so far

Comment: My server is in php if that makes a difference

Comment: And it's a localhost

Comment: Best answer, it helped me a lot. Thank you. I was looking for this for a day.

Comment: Anyone know How to change request body to XML to accept XML input instead of JSON?

Comment: @LêKhánhVinh your question is unrelated to this particular issue. Please post a new question instead of commenting on this one.

Comment: The whole point of `AFJSONRequestSerializer` is to serialise the request for you. So you don't need any of the `NSJSONSerialization` stuff at the start, just pass your `body` dictionary in as the parameters to `requestWithMethod:URLString:parameters:error:`

Comment: Also you don't need to set `Content-Type` this is done for you as well.

Answer (score 65):

Another way to call a POST method with AFNetworking 3.0 is:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc]initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[manager POST:url parameters:parametersDictionary progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"success!");
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
    }];
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: sorry, this isn't what i was looking for. I needed someone way to be able to send the JSON body in the post request. Previously the HTTPBody on the request was the way. I figured out the new way which i posted above

Comment: The serializer converts the NSDictionary to JSON.
I just tested this code with my webService and I received a JSON in the body.

Comment: my JSON body I don't mean the content type, I mean send a JSON string in the body of the HTTP request. Like:

`NSDictionary *body = @{@"snippet": @{@"topLevelComment":@{@"snippet":@{@"textOriginal":self.commentToPost.text}},@"videoId":self.videoIdPostingOn}};

NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:body
   options:0
     error:&error];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

so here I want to send the `[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]` in the request's HTTPBody

Comment: I've tried using the above methods but they never work for me. here is my code:
http://pastebin.com/wAdrUXB6

This is what I tried before:
http://pastebin.com/ZM7gq2Mc

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Midas, to use the method above change "url" parameter to your string "PNGServerApiURL" and change "parametersDictionary" to your dictionary "params". Example:

[manager POST: PNGServerApiURL parameters: params progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"success!");
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
    }];

Comment: I tried that, im not sure if it's an issue that im trying to POST to a localhost?

Comment: And my server is in php

Answer (score 9):

Accepted answer of #Pranoy C is converted for AFNetworking 3.0

```
    NSError *writeError = nil;

    NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&writeError];
    NSString* jsonString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData  timeoutInterval:120];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue: @"application/json; encoding=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue: @"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setHTTPBody: [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

    [[manager dataTaskWithRequest:request uploadProgress:nil downloadProgress:nil completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {

        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"Reply JSON: %@", responseObject);

            if ([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
                //blah blah
            }
        } else {

            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            NSLog(@"Response: %@",response);
            NSLog(@"Response Object: %@",responseObject);

        }
    }] resume];
```

Answer (score 8):

For `HTTPBody` with JSON

```
[sessionManager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[sessionManager.requestSerializer setQueryStringSerializationWithBlock:^NSString *(NSURLRequest *request, id parameters, NSError * __autoreleasing * error) {

    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:error];
    NSString *argString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return argString;
}];

[sessionManager POST:urlString parameters:parameters progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {

    if (completion) {
        completion(responseObject, nil);
    }

} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {

    if (completion) {
        NSData *errorData = [error.userInfo objectForKey:@"com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data"];
        NSDictionary *responseErrorObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:errorData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
        completion(responseErrorObject, error);
    }
}];
```

For `HTTPBody` with custom String format

```
[sessionManager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[sessionManager.requestSerializer setQueryStringSerializationWithBlock:^NSString *(NSURLRequest *request, id parameters, NSError * __autoreleasing * error) {

    NSString *argString = [self dictionaryToString:parameters];
    return argString;
}];

[sessionManager POST:urlString parameters:parameters progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {

    if (completion) {
        completion(responseObject, nil);
    }

} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {

    if (completion) {
        NSData *errorData = [error.userInfo objectForKey:@"com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data"];
        NSDictionary *responseErrorObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:errorData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
        completion(responseErrorObject, error);
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 6):

```
 -(void)postRequest:(NSString *)urlStr parameters:(NSDictionary *)parametersDictionary completionHandler:(void (^)(NSString*, NSDictionary*))completionBlock{
        NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];

        AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
        manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
        [manager POST:URL.absoluteString parameters:parametersDictionary progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
            NSError* error;
            NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject
                                                                 options:kNilOptions
                                                                   error:&error];

            completionBlock(@"Success",json);
        } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            completionBlock(@"Error",nil);
        }];
    }
```

This method is working fine for AFNetworking 3.0.

Answer (score 5):

Use common `NSObject` Class method for Calling Wenservices with **AFNetworking 3.0**
This is my Duplicate Answer but it was **Updated with AFNetworking 3.0**
First make `NSObject` Class Like **Webservice.h** and **Webservice.m**

**Webservice.h**

```
@interface Webservice : NSObject

+  (void)requestPostUrl:(NSString *)strURL parameters:(NSDictionary *)dictParams success:(void (^)(NSDictionary *responce))success failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure;

@end
```

**Webservice.m**       your nsobject.m file is look like this.(*add two functions in .m file*)

```
#import "Webservice.h"

#define kDefaultErrorCode 12345

@implementation Webservice

+  (void)requestPostUrl:(NSString *)strURL parameters:(NSDictionary *)dictParams success:(void (^)(NSDictionary *responce))success failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure {

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    [manager setResponseSerializer:[AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer]];

    [manager POST:strURL parameters:dictParams progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
        if([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            if(success) {
                success(responseObject);
            }
        }
        else {
            NSDictionary *response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
            if(success) {
                success(response);
            }
        }

    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        if(failure) {
            failure(error);
        }

    }];
}

@end
```

> make sure you have to replace your dictionary key with *success* and
>   *message* for handling of responce callback function

**Use like this** call this common method from any **viewcontroller.m**  and any methods from any `viewControllers`. for temporary i am using `viewDidLoad` for calling This WS.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        NSDictionary *dictParam = @{@"parameter1":@"value1",@"parameter1":@"value2"};

        [Webservice requestPostUrl:@"add your webservice URL here" parameters:dictParam success:^(NSDictionary *responce) {
            //Success
            NSLog(@"responce:%@",responce);
            //do code here
        } failure:^(NSError *error) {
            //error
        }];
    }
```

add your Parameter, values and webservice URL in above method. you can easily use this `NSObjcet` Class. for more details please visit [AFNetworking 3.0](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) or [my old answear with AFNetworking 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33767908/volunteermatch-api-objective-c/33886449#33886449).

Answer (score 4):

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:log.text, @"email", pass.text, @"password", nil];
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];

[manager POST:@"add your webservice URL here" parameters:dict progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);   
} 
failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 *  Services gateway
 *  Method  get response from server
 *  @parameter              -> object: request josn object ,apiName: api endpoint
 *  @returm                 -> void
 *  @compilationHandler     -> success: status of api, response: respose from server, error: error handling
 */
+ (void)getDataWithObject:(NSDictionary *)object onAPI:(NSString *)apiName withController:(UIViewController*)controller
                         :(void(^)(BOOL success,id response,NSError *error))compilationHandler {


    controller = controller;
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    // set request type to json
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];


    // post request to server
    [manager POST:apiName parameters:object success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        // NSError *error;
        NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:responseObject
                                                           options:0
                                                             error:&error];

        //NSString *JSONString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[jsonData bytes] length:[jsonData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        //// 

        // check the status of API
        NSDictionary *dict = responseObject;
        NSString *statusOfApi = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@"
                                 ,[dict objectForKey:@"OK"]];

        // IF Status is OK -> 1 so complete the handler
        if ([statusOfApi isEqualToString:@"1"] ) {

            [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
            compilationHandler(TRUE,responseObject,nil);

        } else {

            [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

            NSArray *errorMessages = [responseObject objectForKey:@"messages"];
            NSString *message = [errorMessages objectAtIndex:0];

            [Utilities showAlertViewWithTitle:apiName message:message];

            compilationHandler(FALSE,responseObject,nil);
        }

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[error localizedDescription]];
        NSLog(@"Message is %@", message);

        NSString *errorMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[error localizedDescription]];
        if (!([message rangeOfString:@"The request timed out."].location == NSNotFound)) {
            [Utilities showAlertViewWithTitle:apiName message:errorMessage];
        }

        compilationHandler(FALSE,errorMessage,nil);
    }];

}
```

Comment: the question is about AFNetworking 3.0, and in that version, there are no AFHTTPRequestOperation

Answer (score -1):

```
- (instancetype)init {
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    [self configureSesionManager];
}
return self;
}

#pragma mark - Private

- (void)configureSesionManager {
sessionManager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
sessionManager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
sessionManager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [sessionManager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];
sessionManager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
sessionManager.requestSerializer.timeoutInterval = 60;
}

#pragma mark - Public

- (void)communicateUsingPOSTMethod:(NSString*)pBaseURL parameterDictionary:(NSDictionary*)pParameterDictionary
                       success:(void(^)(id))pSuccessCallback failure:(void(^)(NSError* error))pFailiureCallback {

[sessionManager POST:pBaseURL parameters:pParameterDictionary progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
    pSuccessCallback(responseObject);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
    pFailiureCallback(error);
}];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "UserDetailObject.h"
#import "AFNetworking.h"
#import "XMLReader.h"

//宏定义成功block 回调成功后得到的信息
typedef void (^HttpSuccess)(id data);
//宏定义失败block 回调失败信息
typedef void (^HttpFailure)(NSError *error);

@interface NetworkManager : NSObject<NSXMLParserDelegate,  NSURLConnectionDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableData *webData;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableString *soapResults;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSXMLParser *xmlParser;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL elementFound;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *matchingElement;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURLConnection *conn;

//请求水文信息数据
+ (void)sendRequestForSQInfo:(UserDetailObject *)detailObject success:(HttpSuccess)success failure:(HttpFailure)failure;

//get请求
+(void)getWithUrlString:(NSString *)urlString success:(HttpSuccess)success failure:(HttpFailure)failure;

//post请求
+(void)postWithUrlString:(NSString *)urlString parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters success:(HttpSuccess)success failure:(HttpFailure)failure;

@end
```

NetworkManager.m

```
    #import "NetworkManager.h"

@implementation NetworkManager
@synthesize webData;
@synthesize soapResults;
@synthesize xmlParser;
@synthesize elementFound;
@synthesize matchingElement;
@synthesize conn;

+ (void)sendRequestForSQInfo:(UserDetailObject *)detailObject success:(HttpSuccess)success failure:(HttpFailure)failure{
    NSString *parameter = @"{\"endDate\":\"2015-06-01 08\",\"beginDate\":\"2015-06-01 08\"}";
    NSString *urlStr = @"http://10.3.250.136/hwccysq/cxf/water";
    NSString *methodName = @"getSqInfo";

    AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

    //回复的序列化
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

    [[manager dataTaskWithRequest:[self loadRequestWithParameter:parameter url:urlStr methodName:methodName] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {

        if (!error) {

            success(responseObject);
        } else {
//            NSLog(@"Error: %@, %@, %@", error, response, responseObject);
            failure(error);
        }

    }] resume];
}

+ (NSMutableURLRequest *)loadRequestWithParameter:(NSString *)parameter url:(NSString *)urlString methodName:(NSString *)methodName{

    NSString *soapMessage =
    [NSString stringWithFormat:
     @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
     "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:agen=\"http://agent.water.tjswfxkh.lonwin.com/\" >"
     "<soapenv:Body>"
     "<agen:%@>"
     "<arg0>%@</arg0>"
     "</agen:%@>"
     "</soapenv:Body>"
     "</soapenv:Envelope>", methodName,parameter,methodName
     ];

    // 将这个XML字符串打印出来
    NSLog(@"%@", soapMessage);
    // 创建URL，内容是前面的请求报文报文中第二行主机地址加上第一行URL字段

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    // 根据上面的URL创建一个请求
    NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString *msgLengt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", [soapMessage length]];
    // 添加请求的详细信息，与请求报文前半部分的各字段对应
    [req addValue:@"application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [req addValue:msgLengt forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    // 设置请求行方法为POST，与请求报文第一行对应
    [req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    // 将SOAP消息加到请求中
    [req setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    return req;
}


//GET请求
+(void)getWithUrlString:(NSString *)urlString success:(HttpSuccess)success failure:(HttpFailure)failure{
    //创建请求管理者
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    //内容类型
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json",@"text/json",@"text/javascript",@"text/html", nil];
    //get请求
    [manager GET:urlString parameters:nil progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull downloadProgress) {
        //数据请求的进度
    } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
        success(responseObject);
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        failure(error);
    }];

}

//POST请求
+(void)postWithUrlString:(NSString *)urlString parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters success:(HttpSuccess)success failure:(HttpFailure)failure{
    //创建请求管理者
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    //
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    //内容类型
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json",@"text/json",@"text/javascript",@"text/html", nil];
    //post请求
    [manager POST:urlString parameters:parameters progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {
        //数据请求的进度
    } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
        success(responseObject);
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        failure(error);
    }];
}


@end
```

then add request in controller

```
UserDetailObject *detailObject = [[UserDetailObject alloc]init];
    [NetworkManager sendRequestForSQInfo:detailObject success:^(id data) {

        NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:data];

        NSError *parseError = nil;
        NSDictionary *dict  = [XMLReader dictionaryForNSXMLParser:parser error:&parseError];

        NSLog(@"JSON: - %@", dict);

    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@",error);
    }];
```

https://github.com/Rita5969/afnetwork3.0-for-webservice