# How to set HTTPBody for AFHTTPSessionManager?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7

How to set `HTTPBody` in Json format for `AFHTTPSessionManager` object and POST request?

Now I have:

```
[self.requestManager.requestSerializer setValue: @"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[self.requestManager POST:@"/api/register/"...
```

I get error:

> Request failed: forbidden (403)

Also I tried:

`self.requestManager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];`

Comment: have you used `constructingBodyWithBlock:` somewhere in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

==> 
[afnetworking 3.0 Migration: how to POST with headers and HTTP Body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34561215/afnetworking-3-0-migration-how-to-post-with-headers-and-http-body)

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];
    [manager setRequestSerializer:[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer]];
    [manager setResponseSerializer:[AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer]];

    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"test": @"this is a test"};

    [manager POST:@"http://www...t" parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {

        NSLog(@"%@",[responseObject description]);

    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
    }];
```

Comment: Edit your answer please

Comment: Thank you, how to set header http param `Authorization`