# AFNetworking post request fails due to nsdictionary value with double quotes

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsdictionary, afnetworking-3

**When I set nsdictionary as request parameters, dictionary values with special character are added with double quotes and that cause the post request to failed but when I use same dictionary values using "Rest client (Chrome Add-ons)"  request post successfully. How to fix the issue?**

for example lat and long should be float value because of special character double quotes are added automatically. Here is my NSDictionary log->

**

```
AptSuiteNo = 20;
BuildingName = "the ";
BuiltInYear = 2014;
BuiltUpAreaSize = 200;
CityName = Dhaka;
CountryName = Bangladesh;
CreateDate = "19-04-2016";
CreatedByCompanyID = 7746;
CreatedByUserID = 7915;
CurrencyID = 1;
Description = "The ";
LastUpdateDate = "19-04-2016";
LastUpdatedByUserID = 7915;
Latitude = "23.832637";
LocalityName = Cantonment;
Longitude = "90.416590";
NeighborhoodName = "Nikunja 2";
PlaceID = ChIJieh0al7GVTcRvMjqALwGYVc;
PostedBy = owner;
Price = 200;
PropertyBathroomNumber = 1;
PropertyBedroomNumber = 1;
PropertyBuildUpAreaSizeTypeID = 1;
PropertyID = 0;
PropertyLotSize = 250;
PropertyLotSizeTypeID = 1;
PropertyName = "the ";
PropertyTransactionTypeCategoryID = 1;
PropertyTransactionTypeID = 1;
PropertyTypeID = 10;
StateName = "Dhaka Division";
StateTicker = "Dhaka Division";
ZipCode = 1229;
```

**

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:RequestURL parameters:[self requestDataString] error:&error];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34561215/afnetworking-3-0-migration-how-to-post-with-headers-and-http-body/36299737#36299737