# AFNetworking 3.0 Post Issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-3

I need the pros here to enlighten me on what's wrong with my code. I'm trying to migrate from 2.x to 3.x and I'm getting a migraine.

```
 AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"email": email, @"password": password};
[manager POST:urlString parameters:parameters progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
    NSString *responseStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *jsonData = [responseStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                                                         options:0
                                                           error:nil];
    if ([[json objectForKey:@"success"] intValue] != 1) {
        UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:self.error_login delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:self.continueButton otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
        [alert show];
    } else {
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
        AccountViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"account"];
        NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[self navigationController] viewControllers]];
        [viewControllers removeLastObject];
        [viewControllers addObject:vc];
        [[self navigationController] setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:NO];
    }
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

The server side keeps showing that the parameters are empty.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated =D

Comment: the code for setting the parameters looks correct for me. are you sure that there are values in `email` and `password`?

Comment: can you print this result `parameters`

Comment: Simple solution use like this....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34561215/afnetworking-3-0-migration-how-to-post-with-headers-and-http-body/36299737#36299737

Comment: @AndréSlotta Very sure there are values. I did an NSLog to check before running the POST

Answer (score 0):

the code for creating the post request is correct. tried it on my own server and it works as expected. so check that the values in `email` and `password` are not `nil` and also check your server code.

you can use a `AFJSONSerializer` to make your completion code a little easier though. then you do not have to convert the `responseObject` yourself since `AFNetworking` takes care of this:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"email": email, @"password": password};
[manager POST:urlString parameters:parameters progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
    NSDictionary *json = responseObject;

    if ([[json objectForKey:@"success"] intValue] != 1) {
        UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:self.error_login delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:self.continueButton otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
        [alert show];
    } else {
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
        AccountViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"account"];
        NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[self navigationController] viewControllers]];
        [viewControllers removeLastObject];
        [viewControllers addObject:vc];
        [[self navigationController] setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:NO];
    }
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: The values when I check in Xcode are not nil, but server shows that nothing is posted. Will take your advice for the AFJSONResponseSerializer

Comment: Could you Show your server's Code maybe?

Answer (score 0):

**AFNetworking 3.0 Post Method code.**
**Note** :- Put this line in .h file.

```
+ (void)requestPostUrl: (NSString *)serviceName parameters:(NSDictionary *)dictParams success:(void (^)(NSDictionary *responce))success failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure;
```

**Note** :- Put this code in .m file.

```
+ (void)requestPostUrl: (NSString *)serviceName parameters:(NSDictionary *)dictParams success:(void (^)(NSDictionary *responce))success failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure {

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[manager.requestSerializer setQueryStringSerializationWithBlock:^NSString * _Nonnull(NSURLRequest * _Nonnull request, id  _Nonnull parameters, NSError * _Nullable __autoreleasing * _Nullable error) {

    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:error];
    NSString *argString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return argString;
}];
//here 'kBaseURL' is Web services base URL and servicesName is Web Services API name, You have to pass from declaration side.
NSString *strService = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",kBaseURL,serviceName];
[manager setResponseSerializer:[AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer]];
//[SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Please wait..."];
[SVProgressHUD show];
[manager POST:strService parameters:dictParams progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {


    if([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {

        if(success) {
            [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
            success(responseObject);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSDictionary *response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
        if(success) {
            [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
            NSLog(@"POST Response  : %@",response);
            success(response);
        }
    }
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

    if(failure) {
        [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
        failure(error);
    }
}];
}
```