# Migrating from AFNetworking 2.5.4 to 3.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I'm trying to migrate this code over to `AFNetworking 3.1` but I'm having some issues with the `HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest` function. From what I can tell it's been deprecated but I don't know what to use instead.

Here is the code:

```
- (AFHTTPRequestOperation *)GET:(NSString *)URLString
                     parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
                timeoutInterval:(NSTimeInterval)timeoutInterval
                        success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success
                        failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self.requestSerializer requestWithMethod:@"GET" URLString:[[NSURL URLWithString:URLString relativeToURL:self.baseURL] absoluteString] parameters:parameters error:nil];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:timeoutInterval];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [self HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:success failure:failure];
    [self.operationQueue addOperation:operation];

    return operation;
}
```

Comment: visit ....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34561215/afnetworking-3-0-migration-how-to-post-with-headers-and-http-body/36299737#36299737

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [README](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/f51f0b8533e1e5d549ef718eed60f7637f249d41/README.md#creating-a-download-task) AFNetworking has switched to NSURLSession. This means that to create a request you do something like this:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/download.zip"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:nil destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {
    NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:NO error:nil];
    return [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];
} completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"File downloaded to: %@", filePath);
}];
[downloadTask resume];
```

Your exact function can't be replicated but you can probably work your way back to the caller of that function and replace it with something similar.