# how can i pass dictionary in json post request using afnetworking 3.0

Tags: ios, objective-c

i am trying to pass dictionary as parameter in afnetworking 3.0

```
     NSDictionary *dictionary=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"meetingTyp",_MeetingTypeId,@"meetinTitle",Meetingtitletxtfld.text,@"meetDescription",Meetingdistxtfld.text,@"startTym",_Starttimestr,@"hours",Meetinglengthtxtfld.text,@"meetOwnId",Useridstr,@"projectId",_ProjId,@"meetDate",[[meetDate componentsSeparatedByString: @" "]objectAtIndex:0],@"meetingId",_MeetingId,@"ConferRoomId",_ConfOwnerId,nil];
```

and implementing post request using afnetworking 3.0 like,

```
  AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
[manager setResponseSerializer:[AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer]];
 manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json", @"text/javascript",@"text/html",@"text/plain",@"application/rss+xml", nil];

[manager POST:meetingupdateurlparams parameters:meetingdictparams progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject)
 {
     NSLog(@"response object is %@",responseObject);
     [delegate meetingupdate:responseObject];
 }
      failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation ,NSError *error)
 {
   NSLog(@"welcome %@",error);
}];
```

but app crashing ,due to

```
  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AFHTTPSessionManager :parameters:progress:success:failure:]:
```

anyone can help in this issuance..Thanks in advance :)

Comment: it may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34561215/afnetworking-3-0-migration-how-to-post-with-headers-and-http-body

Comment: i cant understand this line..NSDictionary *body = @{@"snippet": @{@"topLevelComment":@{@"snippet":@{@"textOriginal":self.commentToPost.text}},@"videoId":self.videoIdPostingOn}};

Comment: you are passing keys as objects and objects as keys in your parameters dictionary. I think this is the problem

Comment: i changed parameters order...but still getting same error...

Comment: can you try allocating NSDictionary only & separate key/values on new line.

Comment: u mean,[dict setValue:@" " forKey:@" "] ?..i tried this process also..

Comment: can you print `meetingupdateurlparams` value. It should not be `nil` and invalid url string?

Comment: ya..all values are not nil....and url string is valid..

Comment: can you print the dictionary, i guess somewhere null value is getting passed.

Comment: not passing any null values in the dictionary...