# Should AFNetworking requests be placed in a NSObject seperate from the view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller, afnetworking, nsobject

Trying to improve my coding style and was wondering what the proper way of going about things is. Should they be placed in a NSObjects separate from the view controller and are there any open source clean code examples for me to reference online available?

Comment: yes!. which AFNetworking you are using AFNetworking 2.0 or 3.0 ?

Comment: i have some code snippes will helps you.

Comment: where can I find them?

Comment: I am using 2.0 AFNetworking

Comment: i will upload give me some time.

Comment: i have added answer if yoiu are stucked anywhere please ping here. Hope it helps you more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use common NSObject Class for Calling WS with **AFNetworking 2.0**
First make NSObject Class with any name here i am creating NSObject Class With name **Webservice.h** and **Webservice.m**

**Webservice.h**

```
@interface Webservice : NSObject

+ (void)callWSWithUrl:(NSString *)stUrl parmeters:(NSDictionary *)parameters success:(void (^)(NSDictionary *response))success failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure;

@end
```

**Webservice.m**       your nsobject.m file is look like this.(*add two functions in .m file*)

```
#import "Webservice.h"

#define kDefaultErrorCode 12345

@implementation Webservice

+ (void)callWSWithUrl:(NSString *)stUrl parmeters:(NSDictionary *)parameters success:(void (^)(NSDictionary *response))success failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure {

    [self requestWithUrl:stUrl parmeters:parameters success:^(NSDictionary *response) {
        //replace your key according your responce with "success"
        if([[response objectForKey:@"success"] boolValue]) {
            if(success) {
                success(response);
            }
        }
        else {
            //replace your key according your responce with "message"
            NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"Error" code:kDefaultErrorCode userInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey:[response objectForKey:@"message"]}];
            if(failure) {
                failure(error);
            }
        }
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        if(failure) {

            failure(error);
        }
    }];
}

- (void)requestWithUrl:(NSString *)stUrl parmeters:(NSDictionary *)parameters success:(void (^)(NSDictionary *response))success failure:(void (^)(NSError *))failure {

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager setResponseSerializer:[AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer]];

    //remove comment if you  want to use header
    //[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

    [manager GET:stUrl parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        if([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            if(success) {
                success(responseObject);
            }
        }
        else {
            NSDictionary *response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
            if(success) {
                success(response);
            }
        }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        if(failure) {
            failure(error);
        }
    }];}

@end
```

> make sure you have to replace your dictionary key with *success* and
>   *message* for handling of responce callback function

**Use like this** call this common method from any **viewcontroller.m**  and any methods from any viewControllers. for temporary i am using viewDidLoad for calling This WS.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSDictionary *dictParam = @{@"parameter1":@"value1",@"parameter1":@"value2"};

    [WebClient requestWithUrlWithResultVerificationWithLoder:@"add your webservice URL here" parmeters:dictParam success:^(NSDictionary *response) {
        //Success
        NSLog(@"responce:%@",response);
        //code here...

    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        //Error
        NSLog(@"error:%@",error.localizedDescription);
    }];


}
```

add your Parameter, values and webservice URL in upper method. you can easyly use this NSObjcet Class. for more details please visit [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33767908/volunteermatch-api-objective-c/33886449#33886449).

Comment: I get a no known class method for the first function even though its declared in the .h

Comment: @ChuckKelly please write your error in detail. please

Comment: A good programmer never writes the same code x2 so shouldn't i find a way to keep failure block contained in this method that makes the request since what should happen is kind of universal in the event of a error.

Answer (score 2):

It's always a good idea to create a model if your app is going to be relying on an construct. I.e if you're building an app which contains a tableview full or photos, it's a good idea to create a model for photos.

---

Here are a few examples:

#### [Clean Table View Code - Objc.io](https://www.objc.io/issues/1-view-controllers/table-views/)

In this tutorial, get an understanding of the best way to populate a tableview, and how the relationship works between a model, a cell, and a tableview.

#### [A Weather App Case Study](https://www.raywenderlich.com/55384/ios-7-best-practices-part-1)

This is an end-to-end walk through of building a model for your tableview, then populating the tableview.

#### [MVC in Objective-C (II): Model](http://angelolloqui.com/blog/27-MVC-in-Objective-C-II-Model)

An overall understanding of how models fit into the MVC pattern.

---

If you want to construct an object form the JSON response you want to something like this:

```
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:0 error:&error];

// Sanity check
if ([json isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){
    NSArray *jsonArray = json[@"items"];

    // Sanity check
    if ([jsonArray isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){
        // Here you go through all your items one by one
        for (NSDictionary *dictionary in jsonArray) {
            Model *staff = [[Staff alloc] init];
            model.id = [dictionary objectForKey:@"id"];
            model.name = [dictionary objectForKey:@"name"];
            model.attribute = [dictionary objectForKey:@"attribute"]; 
            // Do this for all your attributes

            [arrayContainingObjects addObject:model];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, it's always a good idea to separate code that accesses a back end server from your UI components. The one best reason being that it's often a requirement for several UI components to access the same server calls.

As far as examples, there are probably thousands. But perhaps a better idea might be to read up on things such as design patterns and app architectural patterns.

objc.io has some [good articles](https://www.objc.io/issues/13-architecture/) on these subjects. Here's [another on Medium](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-architecture-patterns-ecba4c38de52#.ovnfxd2rf). There are lots of other, just google search.

Comment: but why is it I NEVER see any code examples of afnetworking requests in NSObjects?

Comment: The answer to that would depend on what examples you look at, if it's just a quick tutorial example, then it could be quick and dirty, so they won't need to show how to use a model (NSObject).