# How can I migrate in AFNetworking 3.0?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking, afnetworking-3

I am migrating in AFNetworking 3.0. I am using AFHTTPRequestOperation in AFNetworking but it was removed in recent updates. I tried all the possible solution. Basically I need to post a JSON with Header. I convert my NSDIctionary into a JSON object then add it as string. Here is the sample JSON with Header of mine

```
RequestHeader={
  "lname" : "sadhsdf",
  "bday" : "2003-03-13",
  "age" : "12",
  "address" : "dsfhskdjgds",
  "gender" : "M",
  "cnumber" : "12312412",
  "fname" : "sadhsdf",
  "RequestType" : "userregistration",
  "Email" : "sldjlkasd@sjdhflksdf.com",
  "status" : "dsfhskdjgds",
  "Password" : "123456"
}
```

RequestHeader is an NSString and the rest are NSDictionary.

How can I apply it in AFNetworking 3.0? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check this link https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-3.0-Migration-Guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://example.com/"];

AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];

NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:

                        height, @"user[height]",

                        weight, @"user[weight]",

                        nil];

[httpClient postPath:@"/myobject" parameters:params 
success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSString *responseStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"Request Successful, response '%@'", responseStr);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"[HTTPClient Error]: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}];
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer I appreciate it so much but It seems that AFHTTPClient is also removed.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/api"];
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:URL sessionConfiguration:configuration];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[params setValue:@"some value" forKey:@"someKey"];

[manager POST:@"search" parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    //If you need to send image
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"my_image.jpg"];
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5) name:@"Image" fileName:@"my_image.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];

} success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {

} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {

}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the official migration guide [here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-3.0-Migration-Guide)

Answer (score 0):

Use common `NSObject` Class for Calling WS with **AFNetworking 3.0**
This is my Duplicate Answer but it was **Updated with AFNetworking 3.0**
First make `NSObject` Class with any name here i am creating `NSObject` Class With name **Webservice.h** and **Webservice.m**

**Webservice.h**

```
@interface Webservice : NSObject

+  (void)requestPostUrl:(NSString *)strURL parameters:(NSDictionary *)dictParams success:(void (^)(NSDictionary *responce))success failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure;

@end
```

**Webservice.m**       your nsobject.m file is look like this.(*add two functions in .m file*)

```
#import "Webservice.h"

#define kDefaultErrorCode 12345

@implementation Webservice

+  (void)requestPostUrl:(NSString *)strURL parameters:(NSDictionary *)dictParams success:(void (^)(NSDictionary *responce))success failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure {

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    [manager setResponseSerializer:[AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer]];

    [manager POST:strURL parameters:dictParams progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
        if([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            if(success) {
                success(responseObject);
            }
        }
        else {
            NSDictionary *response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
            if(success) {
                success(response);
            }
        }

    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        if(failure) {
            failure(error);
        }

    }];
}

@end
```

> make sure you have to replace your dictionary key with *success* and
>   *message* for handling of responce callback function

**Use like this** call this common method from any **viewcontroller.m**  and any methods from any `viewControllers`. for temporary i am using `viewDidLoad` for calling This WS.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        NSDictionary *dictParam = @{@"parameter1":@"value1",@"parameter1":@"value2"};

        [Webservice requestPostUrl:@"add your webservice URL here" parameters:dictParam success:^(NSDictionary *responce) {
            //Success
            NSLog(@"responce:%@",responce);
            //do code here
        } failure:^(NSError *error) {
            //error
        }];
    }
```

add your Parameter, values and webservice URL in above method. you can easily use this `NSObjcet` Class. for more details please visit [AFNetworking 3.0](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) or [my old answear with AFNetworking 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33767908/volunteermatch-api-objective-c/33886449#33886449).

Comment: Thank you so much for this you saved my day!

Comment: @RyanEnguero Welcome.